# Flummoxed trying to play mp3 in <audio> element. Console says, "Media resource XYZ could not be decoded"

Tags: django, html, audio, localhost, html5-audio

I'm pulling my hair out trying to get the HTML5 `<audio>` element to work. I've got a fairly basic webpage that contains two elements. The first is the one I want on the page, serving a file from my server. The second serves the mp3 from the source server where I got it:

```
<audio preload="metadata" controls="" src="/mp3/2014/09/23/from-the-court.mp3"></audio>
<audio preload="metadata" controls="" src="http://media.ca7.uscourts.gov/sound/external/gw.12-2080.12-2080_09_23_2014.mp3"></audio>
```

The file that's in both of those elements is the same one, bit for bit, but when I load the page, only the latter `<audio>` element shows up. The first one shows up briefly then disappears, with an error in the console saying:

```
 Media resource http://localhost:8000/mp3/2014/09/23/from-the-court.mp3 could not be decoded.
```

It's the same file. Why can't it be decoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it! The file was being sent with x-sendfile, which doesn't work in the development server. Hence the mp3 getting served only ever had 0 bytes of data, despite looking like it worked properly.

Solution is to either use Apache as my development server (no thank you) or disable x-sendfile on development machines.

Comment: `Disable x-sendfile on development machines.` can you please elaborate i have same issue with videos

Comment: I tweaked the view that serves audio files so that it serves the file directly if `settings.DEVELOPMENT is True`.